# Как определить количество способов выбросить определенное число четырьмя игровыми костями?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

Есть 4 игральных кости, какая вероятность того, что сумма всех выпавших чисел будет (для программы нужно выбрать свое число от 4 до 24) к примеру 14. По какой формуле программе легче будет это просчитать?

Comment: Количество комбинаций при 4 костях равно `6^4 = 1296`. Чтобы найти ответ, нужно поделить количество комбинаций, которые дают нужную сумму, на 1296.

Comment: вопрос в том, сколько комбинаций будет.. именно при нужной сумме очков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего использовать рекуррентное соотношение - число способов получить сумму *K* из *M* костей равно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так далее, до [image: введите сюда описание изображения], каковое равно 1 при [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и 0 в противном случае.

```
int N(int L, int M)
{
    int s = 0;
    if (L == 1) return (1 <= M && M <= 6) ? 1 : 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) s += N(L-1,M-i);
    return s;
}
```

Ну, а вероятность получить сумму *K* равна [image: введите сюда описание изображения]...

Можно, конечно, посмотреть [сюда](https://oeis.org/A063260) или использовать какую-нибудь аппроксимирующую формулу - но, как по мне, оно того не стоит.